# Unable to delete Charts while deleting specific columns in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove some columns based on different conditions. These column sets are having tables along with their respective charts below them. When i run the code line by line, it works perfect but when i run the complete code then it works well on the tables but the charts below them doesn't delete at all.

[source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoSuz.jpg)

```
If oper(j) = "ABC" Then

   wtemp.Sheets("Graphs").Range("A:H, Q:AF").Delete

         ElseIf oper(j) = "XYZ" Then

               wtemp.Sheets("Graphs").Range("A:P, Y:AF").Delete

                    ElseIf oper(j) = "KHG" Then

                          wtemp.Sheets("Graphs").Range("A:X").Delete

                    Else

                    wtemp.Sheets("Graphs").Range("I:AF").Delete

End If
```

Comment: Excel charts are objects, they are not the contents of cells. Delete them from the `.Charts` collection.

Comment: Do the charts appear intact, like nothing happened, or do they move / resize? If they remain intact, they have the "Don't  move or size with cells" option. If they move and become ridiculously small, they just are larger than the columns you delete.

Comment: @AlexP Yes they can be deleted from .charts but in my case i want them to move with the table above them after the deletion of other ranges. Also i wonder why everything is working fine when i run it line by line.

Comment: @Excelosaurus Yes, the charts are intact...no movement and no size change. I checked the chart properties and it is checked as "Move and size with cells". Also when i run the code in steps, i get the required result, the tables along with the charts moves to the initial point after deletion of other columns but it's not the same when i run the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

A `ChartObject`'s `Placement` property controls the way it is attached to its underlying cells; see [XlPlacement Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlplacement-enumeration-excel). The chart objects that remain (after columns completely covering them are deleted) most probably have `Placement = xlFreeFloating`.

Here's a sub to handle this situation. It first buffers the `Placement` values, then performs the column deletion, and re-establishes the original `Placement` values.

```
Public Sub DeleteColumnsAndCharts(ByVal pColumnsToDelete As Excel.Range)
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim PlacementByChartName As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim chartsWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim chart As Excel.ChartObject

    Set PlacementByChartName = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set chartsWorksheet = pColumnsToDelete.Worksheet

    'Keep the original Placement values before changing them.
    For Each chart In chartsWorksheet.ChartObjects
        PlacementByChartName(chart.Name) = chart.Placement
        chart.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next

    'Should the Delete method below fail, the Recover section will leave the worksheet intact.
    pColumnsToDelete.EntireColumn.Delete

Recover:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Restore the original Placement values on the remaining chart objects.
    For Each chart In chartsWorksheet.ChartObjects
        chart.Placement = PlacementByChartName(chart.Name)
    Next
    Set chart = Nothing
    Set chartsWorksheet = Nothing
    Set PlacementByChartName = Nothing
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Recover
End Sub
```

You can call it like this:

```
DeleteColumnsAndCharts wtemp.Sheets("Graphs").Range("A:X")
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this and providing solution but even after using thia code the charts are intact with no moment at all. After the final run, i am getting the correct result for tables but no any help with the graphs.

Comment: I can't think of a way to reproduce your issue without involving the `Placement` property. You've mentioned that stepping through the code works whereas it doesn't otherwise; this makes me wonder whether a call to `DoEvents` after column deletion would help (are you deleting in a loop?).

Comment: Yes, i am making this deletion inside a outer "for each" and an inner "for" loop....i also tried to use DoEvents as it is working fine while stepping through the code but that also didn't work out.

Comment: If you can make a skeleton workbook where the problem occurs, share it and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: You can get the file through https://ufile.io/d1wt0. I am having 4 similar files in one folder and for each file i need to delete the unnecessary column ranges one by one and save them. Just for example: The file i shared has name "Hygiene_ABC_go", so only the column with name ABC needs to be present in that file and saved after deletion of other columns.

Comment: Got your file, put the code in it, and called `DeleteColumnsAndCharts Sheet1.Range("R:AF"):DeleteColumnsAndCharts Sheet1.Range("B:H"):?Sheet1.ChartObjects.Count` from the Immediate Window. Works as expected; 3 charts are left under the ABC header. That's on Excel 2016.

Comment: I too get the code running perfectly for this dummy sheet but when i insert this in my main code where it runs under a loop then the things don't work out. I am having four similar files in a folder and had to do the same thing on these four files with respective column headers. I think there might be some problem in running this code under the For Each Loop.